# How to maintain PNG alpha transparency when using "-ms-filter" property

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, png, opacity

I have the following HTML:

```
<a><img src="myfile.png" /> Some text</a>
```

And this css:

```
a:hover
{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75);
    opacity: .75;
}
```

The problem with this occurs in both IE 8 and IE 7.

When the PNG image is subject to the *-ms-filter* or *filter*, its alpha transparency is ruined. Try it out and you will see. It is a bug in both IE 8 and IE 7.

Can I remove the "-ms-opacity" and "filter" properties applied in CSS? What is the syntax for this? (e.g. something like *-ms-filter: "";*)

Does anyone know a work around to this issue?

Comment: I don't think we understood your question. Could you try reword it?

Comment: @SpliFF et al. - Can someone please add (or edit) an answer to give the css required to make a png with partial transparency display with 75% opacity in IE 7 and 8. This is the original question and no answer is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: [AlphaImageLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969.aspx) filter applied directly to the img may override the Alpha filter. As for removing a filter have you tried `filter:none;` ?

Yes, programmically target IE6 and below with conditional comments.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style>a:hover{filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75);}</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Also scripts like [IE7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) will handle PNG transparency for you without cluttering up your CSS with non-standard code.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Sorry I am not interested in IE 6 - I am trying to get this working in IE7 and IE8 when using the '-ms-filter' or 'filter' css properties.

Comment: The solution works for ie7 too. just change the condition to lt IE8 and the script to ie8.js

Comment: But the problem is occurring in IE 8 even: when you apply either the 'filter' or '-ms-filter' properties in CSS, any PNG alpha transparency no longer works.

Comment: ah.. ok, I misunderstood the question. Maybe try applying an AlphaImageLoader filter directly to the image and see if it overrides the Alpha filter on the A.

Comment: well, I also need to remove the filter in style override (think .loading or .active css classes), filter:none does not work :(

Answer (score 10):

Just embellishing SpliFF's answer, I could fix this problem by adding the following jQuery to my page:

```
$(function() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
        $('img[src$=".png"]').each(function() { // must have quotes around .png
            this.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="+this.src+",sizingMethod='scale')";
        });
});
```

This will apply the AlphaImageLoader too all PNGs in the page.

Comment: This little script (and a few span tags around the images I'd like to fade) is a wonder and a treasure for those who have to wrestle with the MSIE abomination.

Answer (score 2):

For people looking for another answer, I solved this using this following code I wrote myself in plain JavaScript, so it's framework independent. Still you have to put it inside your framework's DOM ready event (or you can use domready.js like I did). It loads all the images with .PNG extension with the AlphaImageLoader. It has to be done before your apply the Alpha filter (you can apply the filter after this code with JS also).

The code below:

```
var i;
for (i in document.images) {
    if (document.images[i].src) {
        var imgSrc = document.images[i].src;
        if (imgSrc.toLowerCase().substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.png') {
            document.images[i].style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='crop',src='" + imgSrc + "')";
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to put it inside conditional comments for IE:

```
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
```

Please let me know if it worked fine.
Kind regards!