# png image shadow not showing in IE7&8

Tags: javascript, css, menu

i have the problem for IE7 and 8 browser in Mozila FF and chrome works finely.

the problem is basically the dropdown menu is made of pang images with shadow effect for menu in this site it shows perfectly when i browsing with Mozila FF & Chrome

But the problem comes when i am browsing the site with IE7 & 8

the menu shows solid border instead of shadow.

and second prob. is when the page loading happen all menu images are showing.

Kindly visit this site

http://thirdgroove.com/

thanx

Comment: It means that you have asked questions, but not officially accepted any of the answers that you have been given. If someone gives you an answer that solves your problem, you should accept the answer - that puts a big green tick next to the answer, and awards points to the person that gave the answer. By doing so, you are helping others find answers to similar questions, whilst at the same time thanking the person that gave you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an IE thing.  It has always had trouble displaying PNGs - even version 8 struggles.  You could try changing it to a PNG8 instead of PNG24.  That might work for IE 7 & 8, but I don't think it will help with IE 6 (you may not be bothered about that).

See:
[How to solve/hack fading semi-transparent PNG bug in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204457/how-to-solve-hack-fading-semi-transparent-png-bug-in-ie8)

and
http://www.mooforum.net/discussion/issue-with-png-transparency-ie8-t2063.html

Comment: how can i convert png 24 to png 8

Comment: ok i have convert it to png8 from png32 using fireworks
but it is still the problem persist

Comment: I notice in your CSS that your are setting `opacity`, and I understand that this can cause problems. See [PNG Transparency Problems in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251416/png-transparency-problems-in-ie8) and [How to maintain PNG alpha transparency when using “-ms-filter” property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004973/how-to-maintain-png-alpha-transparency-when-using-ms-filter-property).