# Rotating a div with png background using the filter:matrix method in IE turns transparency into black on background

Tags: css

I want to rotate a div that has a semitransparent shadow as background on it but after rotating in ie6-9 png backgrounds semi-transparent parts turn into black.I use proprietary filter matrix to rotate the div.I tried alphaimageloader and chroma filter with solid color but none of this worked the way I wanted.Anyone knows a solution for this?

The code:

```
#target {
    background:url(left.png) no-repeat 0 0;width:95px;height:109px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.99619470, M12=0.08715574, M21=-0.08715574, M22=0.99619470,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.99619470, M12=0.08715574, M21=-0.08715574, M22=0.99619470,sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try it myself yet, but I think one of the following may help:

- http://www.viget.com/inspire/jquery-ie-png-24-ie-black-background-issue-solved/
- http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/
- [How to maintain PNG alpha transparency when using "-ms-filter" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004973/how-to-maintain-png-alpha-transparency-when-using-ms-filter-property)